# How do I find the virtualenv path installed via wsl2 when choosing python interpreter in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, wsl-2

I clicked "python: select interpreter - enter interpreter path - find"

But I can't find that path.

How do I find and select interpreter path?

Answer (score 0):

You need to point to the `python.exe` which is under the installation location of the python.

If you don't know where the `python.exe` is, you can find it in the `cmd` with the command of `where python`. And of course, you need to add the python installation location to the system environment variable of `path` first.